# No error but could not invoke method with hangfire

Tags: c#, hangfire

I am using C# hangfire. This is my code. I have no error running all these code. But my problem is it doesn't invoke SendEmail function. What are the possible issues which cause this?

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Schedule")]
public IActionResult Schedule() {
    BackgroundJob.Enqueue<IService>(x => x.SendEmail());
    return Ok("Background job started.");
}
```

Comment: The credential are not correct.  How is the server running?  Is it running as a Server?  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs?force_isolation=true

Comment: what do you mean? I am not using web form. This is web api controller with hangfire.

Comment: You appication is still a http client connecting to a server and you need credentials.  You also need credentials to send email.  It is a web application.  A controller receives an http connection and parses the results.  It is a two port application since it receives on one port and then sends email on a second port. So above coded is a server on first connection, sends email, and then sends a 200 OK message back to the first client with a body "Background job started".  So I would debug the SendEmail method.  You will not get an error since the SendEmail is done as a background task.

Comment: Actually my sendemail is just empty method. I put the debug break point there but it didn't reach there. Not sure why it doesn't reach there even the code run without error

Comment: Either the connection doesn't complete or the Route is wrong.  Looks like you have other postings using hangfire and I assume then work. What is different with new app?  Are you using same client and server machines?  Are you using same user acounts?  Did you upgrade any versions of software?  Do your previous apps still work?